# vs2008 extension access user file

Tags: visual-studio-2008, vspackage, vsprops

One of my vc2008 project is under version control, and it depends on boost and some other libraries, but in my machine, the boost root directory $BOOST the project refers to is not the same as my teammate's, and I don't like to put $BOOST into system environment.

Propertysheet is a solution but it's not convenient to put the .vsprops file under version control since everyone is different, and my teammate doesn't want to use it because he already defined $BOOST in system variable. If I commit my .vcproj inheriting from .vcprops and ignore the .vcprops, my teammate then will not open the project properly after update since he don't have my .vsprops file.

At last, I find out that I can keep optional $BOOST in the .vcproj.machine.someone.user file and the .vcproj.user file by hand, vs2008 always wipe out unnecessary content it think in .vcproj.machine.someone.user file when saving, so the only one I can use is .vcproj.user.

Now I'd like to add some UI elements to vs2008 to access the .vcproj.user file, how can I access it via vs2008 sdk? is there any example?